# Android: ERROR: Failed to resolve: cardview Affected Modules: app

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have to migrate my project to AndroidX to support a certain third part library but when I try to migrate using Android Studio provided tool through **Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX**  I always get this error

```
ERROR: Failed to resolve: cardview Affected Modules: app
```

here are my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.2-alpha02'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-alpha02'

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5'
    implementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.thoughtbot:expandablerecyclerview:1.3'
    implementation 'com.robertlevonyan.view:MaterialChipView:1.2.5'
    implementation 'com.github.tcking:giraffeplayer2:0.1.19-lazyLoad'
    implementation 'com.github.faruktoptas:FancyShowCaseView:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.sundeepk:compact-calendar-view:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.cdflynn:turn-layout-manager:v1.2'
    implementation 'com.github.takusemba:multisnaprecyclerview:1.3.3'
    implementation 'com.ramotion.cardslider:card-slider:0.3.0'
    implementation 'com.ramotion.circlemenu:circle-menu:0.3.2'
    //    implementation 'com.github.halilozercan:BetterVideoPlayer:1.2.alpha1'
    implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.budiyev.android:circular-progress-bar:1.2.2'
    implementation 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.3.1'
    implementation 'fm.jiecao:jiecaovideoplayer:5.7'
    implementation 'com.github.cdflynn:turn-layout-manager:v1.2'
    implementation 'io.github.yavski:fab-speed-dial:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.2'

    //animation library
    implementation 'com.daimajia.easing:library:2.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'
    //    implementation 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.37.0'
    //    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Migrating to android x has weird bugs updating your android studio to newest version might solve it

also you can set `android.enablejetifier` to `false` in `gradle.properties` and you won't see this error but you should use androidx libraries